# Revoke Push Notification

Tags: uwp, wns

I sent a push notification to a Windows 10 Mobile device via the Windows Push Notification Service. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview

How can I revoke this message from the device using the Push Notification Service?

Comment: What you mean? You want to revoke your pushed notification from service?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.